# Different 404 error page depending on the user role

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm developing a web application using spring mvc, and spring-security for authentication.
So I have three roles: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONS and ROLE_CP
And I have three 404 pages 404CP.jsp, 404Cons.jsp and 404Admin.jsp
But the problem is that I only know how to specify the error page for the whole application, in web.xml file:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/presentation/404CP.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

So I want to know how to specify a different 404 page for each role

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notFound</location>
</error-page>
```

ErrorController:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/notFound")
    public String notFound(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "404Admin";
        } else if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_CONS")) {
            return "404Cons";
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

The error pages must be in the directory where your views are located (so that they will be correctly resolved by the view resolver).